# Grub2 rescue with Win7 & Ubuntu

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2

I installed the Ubuntu 14.04 and a Windows 7 in the same HD. And everything was working, but I created another partition in Windows to store data. And now I can't boot.

```
error unknown filesystem
grub rescue >
```

How I can restore the grub?

Comment: i have added an answer, check it

Answer (score 0):

First thing to try: Boot a live USB or CD and run [boot-repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair)

Answer (score 0):

Do you still have your live medium? A usb stick or a dvd with an Ubuntu live system? Boot from it.

Enter `lsblk` to find out the name of your hdd. For me the output is

```
$ lsblk
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda      8:0    0 238.5G  0 disk 
├─sda1   8:1    0   100M  0 part 
├─sda2   8:2    0  79.9G  0 part 
├─sda3   8:3    0     1K  0 part 
├─sda5   8:5    0     5G  0 part 
└─sda6   8:6    0 153.5G  0 part /
sr0     11:0    1  1024M  0 rom
```

so my hdd is `/dev/sda`.

Then enter these commands:

```
sudo grub-install /dev/sda
sudo update-grub
```

Reboot and you're done.

Answer (score 0):

Boot into Ubuntu live from DVD or USB.

Open terminal by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>. Then execute following command :

```
sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair && sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && boot-repair
```

Reboot and you are done!